# NavigationServiceNavigate not working WP7

Tags: navigationservice

When I use this in my .NET codebehind:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("DetailsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

I get redirected to App.xaml.cs and it points to this code.

```
    // Code to execute if a navigation fails
    private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? The files are in the same directory.. and the spelling is correct. I'm using the navigation from `MainPage.xaml` going to `DetailsPage.xaml`.. using an application bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this instead:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Folder/DetailsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Where Folder - location of where pages located.

Comment: NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));     worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a / 
it should be like NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));